# Browser complains about Wildcard SSL Certificate when tunneling

Tags: ssl

I just bought a Wildcard SSL Certificate from COMODO and everything works as expected. The only thing that bothers me is when I open an SSH tunnel to a machine that uses that certificate and thus type something like that in my browse,

```
https://localhost:10003/app/
```

chrome complains about the fact that the server uses a certificate for *.mydomain.com on the "localhost" domain.

Is there anything I could do to prevent that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - that is EXACTLY what SSL is SUPPOSED to do.

Your Cert is for *.mydomain.com, and localhost is NOT in *.mydomain.com, so the cert is not valid.

Fixing your "problem" would mean breaking SSL.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense...